# Application Icons getting blurred

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

While developing app for iOS and Android in Xamarin, menu items, toolbar items or any other icon goes to blurry.

I’m using Lunar to get icons as `.png` I dont know what is the problem, icons are not in shape.
For example grid row is 55 px, I use image for icon and set aspect to aspectfit but nothing changes.

Anybody has an idea about this?

Comment: can you show an example of the actual image and a screenshot of it rendering "blurry"?

Comment: Hello Jason, thanks for your interest :) I am not near my PC now. I’ll send you a example of screeshot as soon as possible.But blurry means resolution problem on icons.For example i take white icons on black panel but they dont look completely as white .. they look more blurred gray

Comment: Make your icon larger. Try 128px by 128px and see how it looks. I say go all out to 512x512, why not -- diskspace is cheap.

Comment: Does your icons have a alpha?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT How can i learn about it ?

Comment: @Andy Okay I ll try it today, after i share the result here:)

Comment: Can you please share us a screenshot?

Comment: @Andy Thank you so much. Previously, I was formatting icons according to the line size, now I get as big as possible, I automatically shape them according to the line problem is solved :)